# How to get all results in a http request python

Tags: python, json, httprequest, python-requests, python-3.5

I am trying to get all results from https://www.ncl.com/. I found that the request must be `GET` and sent to this link:https://www.ncl.com/search_vacations
so far i got the first 12 results and there is no problem parsing them. The problem is i cannot find a way to "change" the page of the results. I get 12 of 499 and i need to get them all. I've tried to do this https://www.ncl.com/search_vacations?current_page=1 and increment it every time but i get the same (first) result every time. Tried adding json body to the request `json = {"current_page": '1'}` again with no success.
This is my code so far:

```
    import math
import requests

session = requests.session()
proxies = {'https': 'https://97.77.104.22:3128'}
headers = {
    "authority": "www.ncl.com",
    "method": "GET",
    "path": "/search_vacations",
    "scheme": "https",
    "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "connection": "keep-alive",
    "referer": "https://www.ncl.com",
    "cookie": "AkaUTrackingID=5D33489F106C004C18DFF0A6C79B44FD; AkaSTrackingID=F942E1903C8B5868628CF829225B6C0F; UrCapture=1d20f804-718a-e8ee-b1d8-d4f01150843f; BIGipServerpreprod2_www2.ncl.com_http=61515968.20480.0000; _gat_tealium_0=1; BIGipServerpreprod2_www.ncl.com_r4=1957341376.10275.0000; MP_COUNTRY=us; MP_LANG=en; mp__utma=35125182.281213660.1481488771.1481488771.1481488771.1; mp__utmc=35125182; mp__utmz=35125182.1481488771.1.1.utmccn=(direct)|utmcsr=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); utag_main=_st:1481490575797$ses_id:1481489633989%3Bexp-session; s_pers=%20s_fid%3D37513E254394AD66-1292924EC7FC34CB%7C1544560775848%3B%20s_nr%3D1481488775855-New%7C1484080775855%3B; s_sess=%20s_cc%3Dtrue%3B%20c%3DundefinedDirect%2520LoadDirect%2520Load%3B%20s_sq%3D%3B; _ga=GA1.2.969979116.1481488770; mp__utmb=35125182; NCL_LOCALE=en-US; SESS93afff5e686ba2a15ce72484c3a65b42=5ecffd6d110c231744267ee50e4eeb79; ak_location=US,NY,NEWYORK,501; Ncl_region=NY; optimizelyEndUserId=oeu1481488768465r0.23231006365903206",
    "Proxy-Authorization": "Basic QFRLLTVmZjIwN2YzLTlmOGUtNDk0MS05MjY2LTkxMjdiMTZlZTI5ZDpAVEstNWZmMjA3ZjMtOWY4ZS00OTQxLTkyNjYtOTEyN2IxNmVlMjlk"
}


def get_count():
    response = requests.get(
        "https://www.ncl.com/search_vacations?cruise=1&cruiseTour=0&cruiseHotel=0&cruiseHotelAir=0&flyCruise=0&numberOfGuests=4294953449&state=undefined&pageSize=10&currentPage=",
        proxies=proxies)
    tmpcruise_results = response.json()
    tmpline = tmpcruise_results['meta']
    total_record_count = tmpline['aggregate_record_count']
    return total_record_count


total_cruise_count = get_count()
total_page_count = math.ceil(int(total_cruise_count) / 10)
session.headers.update(headers)
cruises = []
page_counter = 1
while page_counter <= total_page_count:
    url = "https://www.ncl.com/search_vacations?current_page=" + str(page_counter) + ""
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxies)
    cruise_results = page.json()
    for line in cruise_results['results']:
        cruises.append(line)
        print(line)
    page_counter += 1
    print(cruise_results['pagination']["current_page"])
    print("----------")
print(len(cruises))
```

Using `requests` and a proxy. Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: first use web browser to see how it works in browser. You may need `requests.Session()` to easily work with cookies.

Comment: Try to create a Session() as suggested and afterwards keep in mind to send the headers with your request (within the headers there are usually the Cookies)

Comment: i am using firefox-developer and session. as you see in the code `session.headers.update(headers)`. Problem is that when i get the response back it says `current_page:1` in the response. That means i must be able to change them. So far i cant find how to do that even in a browser.

Comment: headers do not include anything about pages or page number. Only user agent and location info.

Comment: posted the entire code

Comment: How do you get `current_page:1` value?

Comment: well i didnt. It is just one of the things ive tried. If you send the request, response will include `pagination` object with `current_page` in it

Comment: Ok so ive tried `GET` request with current_page/currentPage/page/p/pn and a `POST` request with all this params and nothing works. Im still getting only a first page of 12 results and `current_page=1` param...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The website claims to have 12264 search results (for a blank search), organised in pages of 12.

The search url takes a parameter `Nao` which seems to define the search result offset from which your result page will start.

So fetching https://www.ncl.com/uk/en/search_vacations?Nao=45

should get a "page" of 12 search results, starting with result 46.

and sure enough:

```
"pagination": {

    "starting_record": "46",
    "ending_record": "57",
    "current_page": "4",
    "start_page": "1",
    ...
```

So to page through all results, start with `Nao` = 0 and add 12 for each fetch.

Comment: I went to the [website](https://www.ncl.com/uk/en/) and entered a blank search in the search box at the top of the page.  The resulting [search page](https://www.ncl.com/uk/en/search?Ntt=) shows pagination links for search results.  Inspecting the pagination links shows that `Nao` increases on each link, and it seemed reasonable to test whether the API responded to the same query parameters.